# How to update or uninstall a custom plugin in Kong Ingress Controller?

Tags: kubernetes, plugins, lua, kubernetes-helm, kong

## Question

What's the proper way (if there is one) to **update an already existing Kong custom plugin**? And what about **uninstalling** it?

## Details

I've been struggling a bit while trying to test and debug my Kong custom plugins.

The documentation provides a section "[Deploying custom plugins](https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/latest/plugins/custom/#deploying-custom-plugins)" that explains how to install the custom plugin, *while installing Kong*, so that it can be used later on.

Given that I already installed Kong, I tried using `helm upgrade`, instead of `helm install`, to update the values. This way I was able to use the plugin the first time:

1. I sent a request to a route using the plugin:

```bash
curl -i localhost/foobar/test/custom/myheader
[...]
```

2. The gateway logs showed the following entry:

```
2023/11/28 09:11:24 [notice] 1262#0: *392 [kong] handler.lua:8 [myheader] "LOG: test", client: X.X.0.1, server: kong, request: "GET /foobar/test/custom/myheader HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
X.X.0.1 - - [28/Nov/2023:09:11:24 +0000] "GET /foobar/test/custom/myheader HTTP/1.1" 200 17 "-" "curl/8.2.1"
```

However, it seems like I cannot change them a second time:

1. I deleted the ConfigMap `kong-plugin-myheader`;
2. I deleted the KongPlugin `my-custom-plugin`;
3. I upgraded helm with an empty `values.yaml`;
4. I created a new ConfigMap `kong-plugin-myheader` with the new code (see below "after");
5. I created a new KongPlugin `my-custom-plugin`;
6. I sent another request, but still see the same log message (therefore I'm guessing the custom plugin was not updated).

To effectively see the changes, I have to uninstall and reinstall Kong entirely. Isn't there a better/quicker approach?

---

### Resources

#### Custom Plugin "myheader"

##### File Structure

```
myheader/
myheader/handler.lua
myheader/schema.lua
```

##### File `handler.lua` before

```lua
local MyHeader = {}

MyHeader.PRIORITY = 1000
MyHeader.VERSION = "1.0.0"

function MyHeader:header_filter(conf)
    -- test
    kong.log('"LOG: test"')
end

return MyHeader
```

##### File `handler.lua` after

```lua
local MyHeader = {}

MyHeader.PRIORITY = 1000
MyHeader.VERSION = "1.0.0"

function MyHeader:header_filter(conf)
    -- test
    kong.log('"LOG: test NEW"')
end

return MyHeader
```

##### File `schema.lua`

```lua
return {
    name = "myheader",
    fields = {
        {
            config = {
                    type = "record",
                    fields = {
                    { header_value = { type = "string", default = "roar", }, },
                },
            }, 
        },
    }
}
```

#### File `values.yaml`

```yaml
gateway:
  plugins:
    configMaps:
    - name: kong-plugin-myheader
      pluginName: myheader
```

#### KongPlugin `my-custom-plugin`

```yaml
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongPlugin
metadata:
  name: my-custom-plugin
config:
  header_value: "my first plugin"
plugin: myheader
```

#### Service `foobar`

```yaml
# Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: foobar
  name: foobar
[...]
---
# Service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: foobar-service
  name: foobar-service
spec:
  [...]
  selector:
    app: foobar # referencing metadata.labels.app (set of key-value)
---
# Route /foobar/test/custom/myheader
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: foobar-route-test-custom-myheader
  annotations:
    konghq.com/strip-path: 'true'
    konghq.com/plugins: 'my-custom-plugin'
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - name: kong
  rules:
  - matches:
    - path:
        type: PathPrefix
        value: /foobar/test/custom/myheader
    backendRefs:
    - name: foobar-service
      kind: Service
      port: 3000
```